# How to disable Fusioncharts legend area?

Tags: fusioncharts

How can I disable/remove the legend area when using FusionCharts? I'll be using a very small chart, so the legend area is not necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding a showLegend='0' tag should disable it.  Use it like this:

`<chart showLegend='0'...>`

Check out [FusionCharts Legend API](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/flex/charts/Contents/xml_elements_legend.html) for more help on legends.

Answer (score 0):

How to set Show legend property to my Fusion Graph.My code like this.

```
   public Pie2DChart GetServiceEsclationChart(DataTable BarChartdt, string CaseType)
    {
        Pie2DChart oChart3 = new Pie2DChart();

        // Set properties
        oChart3.Background.BgColor = "ffffff";
        oChart3.Background.BgAlpha = 50;
        oChart3.ChartTitles.Caption = "Case Type Count";
        oChart3.ChartTitles.Caption = CaseType;
        // oChart.ChartTitles.SubCaption = "2013-2014 Year";

        // Set a template
        oChart3.Template = new Libero.FusionCharts.Template.OfficeTemplate();

        // Set data             
        oChart3.DataSource = BarChartdt;
        oChart3.DataTextField = "Name";
        oChart3.DataValueField = "Value";


        //Load it into ViewData.
        // ViewData["SREsclation"] = oChart3;
        return oChart3;
    }
```